# Mysql error on AWS ECS: [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-efs

I've got a project that works fine on AWS, using ECS/fargate. The setup is composed of 3 containers, one of which runs a mysql DB.

To ensure the DB data persists beyond the container lifecycles, I created and mapped an EFS as a volume to my ECS task,

```
 "volumes": [
    {
      "name": "mysql",
      "efsVolumeConfiguration": {
        "fileSystemId": "fs-xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      }
    }
  ]
```

and then mounted that to the container definition:

```
 "mountPoints": [
    {
     "sourceVolume": "mysql",
     "containerPath": "/var/lib/mysql",
     "readOnly": false
   }
 ]
```

But here's the issue: All further deployments after this change was made have been failing because of this error from the mysql container:

`[ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11`

From my understanding, it seems when a new deployment is pushed to ECS, the newly deployed mysql container tries to perform some actions on the file: ./ibdata1 but it's unable to. This is because the file may still be open and in use by the existing container. Is this correct?

I am not sure how to go about this. Using RDS is not an option at this point.

I can confirm all necessary read and write permissions are available on that file. I can also confirm that restarting the task (using any of the older revision) works fine. Also, the DB data is available on the EFS, as configured.

But I just can't get pass that error when I deploy afresh. I'd appreciate any help or pointers.

Comment: Running a database in ECS (and especially Fargate) is just a horrible idea. You run into all sorts of issues like the one you are running into now. Using EFS as the disk volume for a database is also a horrible idea because it is pretty much the slowest persistent disk option on AWS, so your DB is going to be slow. You should really consider moving the database portion of your application into AWS RDS MySQL or Aurora MySQL.

Comment: The actual issue you are running into is because you can only have a single MySQL container running at a time with that disk volume setup you have. You would need to configure ECS to stop the running MySQL container before even trying to start a new one. Right now you are probably using the default deployment configuration, which tries to start the new task/containers and wait for it to be healthy before stopping the old ones. But this isn't scalable at all and any sort of container crash could leave your application unable to automatically recover without your manual deleting of the file.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mark. 

The goal was to have a direct replica of the dev workflow in production, without the need for a separate DB solution like RDS. 

No traffic or any serious user activity is expected on this project, it's just a showcase. Also, the goal was to deploy and let ECS manage all the core components of the project.

But not withstanding, I may just have to change the setup and switch to RDS. Thank you once again.